# How to pull lambda code & config with SAM CLI

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, jetbrains-ide, aws-sam-cli

Currently I'm working with online editor on AWS to code my lambdas.. and it's boring. That's why I want to code with my own editor (JetBrains).

The problem is that I don't know how to pull code & config of my lambda (with SAM CLI not AWS CLI) in my SAM project. I can just push code but not pull.

How can I pull my lambda code & config from AWS with SAM CLI?

Comment: I have the same issue did you manage to solve it?